# undefined method `enqueue_active_job' for CarrierWave::Backgrounder:Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, rails-activejob

I'm using `carrierwave` and `carrierwave_backgrounder` to store images on S3, but move image processing to a separate worker. My goal is to use the ActiveJob inline queue to process the images immediately when running locally, and use Sidekiq on production.

I'm working with the following code:

`// models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  mount_uploader :cover_photo, CoverPhotoUploader
  process_in_background :cover_photo
...
end`

`// uploaders/cover_photo_uploader.rb
class CoverPhotoUploader < ImageUploader
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  version :mobile do
    process resize_to_limit: [380,nil]
   end
end`

`// config/initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :active_job, queue: :carrierwave
end`

When I try to upload an image, I get:

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'enqueue_active_job' for CarrierWave::Backgrounder:Module):`

I'm not really sure how to debug this any further. When switching `backgrounder` to use `sidekiq` as the backend, things work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was failing to pass the ActiveJob to `process_in_background`, [as specified here](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder#override-worker).

Looking through this [repo](https://github.com/piotrkaczmarek/backgrounder_test) really helped me.